# How to use SpiderMonkey on Windows

Tags: javascript, c

I would like to use SpiderMonkey ( the javascript engine from Mozilla ) in my application. I want to use the js3250.dll shipped with firefox but i have a pb from the very beginning. It seems that the JS_NewRuntime method is not available anymore (according to the depends tool ).
Any idea how to embed the javascript engine into another app ( C or Python) ?

Thx

Comment: If you can do C++, V8 is a great choice as an alternative and really easy.

Comment: V8 is great, but I haven't found SpiderMonkey to be much more difficult.  It really depends on what you are trying to do.  If you just want speed and only care about vanilla js then go with V8.  We choose SpiderMonkey in the end because of E4X and fell in love with it for generators, destructuring assignments and array comprehension.  Mozilla has added support for javascript features that no one else has covered yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS_NewRuntime should certainly still be available.

There is a lot of documentation available in the MDC.  I would start with the embedding tutorials linked on [this Mozilla page](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) if you're starting from ground zero.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what i have started to do, but i can't find the entry point for the engine ( JS_NewRuntime ) . Do you know if js3250.dll contains this function on Win32?

Comment: It certainly does.  I'm using it in this way: _runtime = JS_NewRuntime(256L * 1024L * 1024L);

Comment: Ah.  In jsapi.h you'll see it's definition: #define JS_NewRuntime JS_Init

Comment: Thx , it works, that was the issue ( i was using it from a foreing function interface lib (ctypes in python) and i didn't have the jsapi.h )
Many thx

Answer (score 0):

see also the source code for [JSDB](http://www.jsdb.org) which uses spidermonkey.